# Is iBatis the right choice for dynamic SQL queries?

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I'm facing the following design issue:

- There will be several prepared SQL statements where the WHERE-clause contains defined contraints in which the values will be dynamic, based on user input.
- In addition there will be some SQL statements required that might end up to be pretty complex, but the resulting SELECT-clause) will still be pretty straight-forward.

As far as I understand iBatis would fit into these requirements.

- Now what happens in a scenario where the user (through a UI) would influence the complete query construction, making the queries on an adhoc basis?

A prepared statement can't do it as the whole WHERE clause is dynamic, we might even have aggregation clauses or even sub-selects built into the SQL functions.

With all of this in mind, would you still go with iBatis or do some other custom development as the best architecture given the above requirements?

Comment: Consider myBatis.  It is the newer version of iBatis.  Development on iBatis has stopped (I believe).  At some point (for reasons I dont know) the project was moved from Apache to Google and the name was changed myBatis.

Comment: Sorry - of course I meant myBatis ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of iBatis (MyBatis) is allowing us to use powerful OGNL based expressions for constructing dynamic queries. One of the most powerful features of iBATIS has always been its Dynamic SQL capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

iBatis would work in this case.  We did the exact same scenario you described using iBatis to create dynamic, adhoc queries, based on user selections from the UI.  The complexity arose as the number of user elements that were made available increased from page to page, but it is doable.

Hibernate is a fully functional ORM that is another obvious option, but it's more complex to use. Here are some links to help:

[Dynamic Queries with Hibernate](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/dynamic_queries_with_hibernate)

[StackOverflow question on Dynamic Queries with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773080/dynamic-queries-with-hibernate)

So I would go with iBatis as a first choice, or Hibernate as a solution.  I think with the complexity a custom solution would too easily turn into a lot of convoluted, nested code, unless you really think through the entire design first.  Assuming of course that the requirements don't change as you go.

I feel iBatis would allow you to better organize the sql code in the endeavor and allow for flexibility in the design in lieu of future changes. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for iBatis. I have always found it best if you have complex SQL queries to be executed (especially a number of JOINs and SUB-selects) that result in a trivial result set.

You have a lot more control over SQL when you use iBatis, and also helps you integrate with existing/legacy databases.